# How to read the stored procedure query from Sql Server 2005 in C#?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2005

I have a simple stored procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[simple]

AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)

    SELECT @sql = '
            SELECT TOP(5) * FROM aTable'
        PRINT @sql

    EXEC sp_executesql 
        @sql
END
```

And now, in C#, I want to get, if is possible, the `@sql` value from stored procedure (after it was executed).

I use Sql Server 2005.

How to do that in **C#**?

Comment: You want the results of the command, or the value of the @sql variable?

Comment: Do you mean: *outside* of (and after) `simple` you want to know `@sql`? or do you mean you want *inside* `simple`, to look at the results of `EXEC sp_executesql @sql` ?

Comment: btw, `SET NOCOUNT ON` shouldn't change anything to do with extra result sets / `SELECT` - it just avoids some informational output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the comments, you want access to `@sql` from C# code *after* calling the method. So:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[simple]
    @sql nvarchar(4000) = null OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT @sql = N'SELECT TOP(5) * FROM aTable'

    EXEC sp_executesql @sql
END
```

then simply in your ADO.NET code:

```
using(var cmd = connection.CreateCommand()) {
    cmd.CommandText = "dbo.simple";
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    var sqlParam = cmd.Parameters.Add("sql", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 4000);
    sqlParam.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
    // TODO here: ExecuteNonQuery, ExecuteReader, etc, i.e. your existing code
    string sql = (string)sqlParam.Value;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You will need to return it explicitly from your SPROC.

You have at least <del>3</del> 2 options here

1. An `OUT` parameter (`CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[simple] @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) OUT`)
2. <del>a `RETURN` value (`RETURN @sql`)</del>
3. Just `SELECT @sql` as the last line of your SPROC

You will need to then bind this in your appropriate technology in your C# code

**EDIT** Return won't work - [Integer expressions only](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174998.aspx)

Re : How do I do this in C#?

Assuming you are using ADO.NET SqlClient:

If you use OUTPUT

```
var myParam = new SqlParameter("@sql", SqlDbType.VarChar);
myParam.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
myCmd.Parameters.Add(myParam);
```

If you use SELECT it will come through as an additional result set to your SPROC. 
Since your proc already emits one result set (by 'sp_executesql  @sql'), this will be the second.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you not using this, what is the need of @sql variable:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[simple]
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT TOP(5) * FROM aTable
END
```

C# code:

```
    SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection("ConnectionString"); 
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("simple", sqlConnection);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    adp.Fill(ds);
```

Answer (score 0):

The [SqlCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.aspx) class has the property CommandText which you can use to read the procedure, "Gets or sets the Transact-SQL statement, table name or stored procedure to execute at the data source." You can find some examples [here](http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorial/AdoDotNet/lesson07).